# Using 1.5 and 1.65 V ram on the same motherboard

Tags: memory

I have an ASRock Fatal1ty P67 Professional mobo with a 2x4GB Corsair XMS3 1.65 V ram kit (CMX8GX3M2A1600C9). I just purchased another 2x4GB kit of Corsair XMS3 ram but these ones didn't have the voltage specified, so they might be 1.5V.
Should I just return them if this is the case or will they work fine, 2x4GB 1.65V along 2x4GB 1.5V?

Comment: The motherboard will set the voltage to the lowest value (1.5V). The result will depend on the ram modules behavior. It may fail or work more slowly it all the modules are able to handle only 1.5V.

Comment: Most modules will tolerate 1.65V, but YMMV. Unfortunately, I don’t have any source on this right now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies. I will post here if the new kit is indeed 1.5V to let you know if it works or not.